# AsyncStorage not persisting my user data in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a login screen, I'm not using Redux and I'm not using Tokens too. The login is working fine, but I can't persist my user data (credentials) on my device, every time that I close my application I have to Log the user in. I set up my AsyncStorage, but doesn't seems to work. Here is my code:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

    //Navigation
    navigate = this.props.navigation

    // State
    state = {
        email: '',
        password: ''
    };
    
    // Route
    login() {
        api.post('users/login', {email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password}).then(data => {
            AsyncStorage.setItem('user', data.data.message);
            this.props.navigation.navigate('MenuScreen');
        }).catch (e => {
            Alert.alert('Credenciais inválidas');
        });
    };

    test() {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('MenuScreen');
    }
    // Email Hook
    handleEmailChange = (email) => {
        this.setState({ email });
    };
    // Pasword Hook 
    handlePasswordChange = (password) => {
        this.setState({ password });
    };
```

On my JSX I just have a button that calls the login and the inputs that work according the hooks.

Comment: I see you setting the asyncstorage, but where are you loading it? You can't expect your application to magically load data from async storage and set everything up properly. You most likely need to do some extra checks in `componentDidMount` (eg. load data from ayncstorage -> if logged in, automatically redirect to MenuScreen -> else, redirect to login screen)

Comment: as @nbokmans figured out you need to call `AsyncStorage.getItem('user');` and handle the data.

Comment: Got it, should I put an if statement checking the getItem and then I direct the navigator to the MenuScreen?

Comment: Another question. Should I use the ComponentDidMount before the login right?